# Got blocking every time when i run the application

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging

Every time when i run the application the app is blocking at App delegte main method.  Its not a crash. When clicking continue its move to next level. I do not have added any break point too. 
I do not understand why its behaving like this.

**Xcode Version 9.0 beta 2 (9M137d)**

Please find the below Image for in detail understanding for understand question.

[image]

In subviewcontroller for the rootviewcontroller

```
static uint64_t startTime;

void startRec(void);
void startRec() {
    startTime = mach_absolute_time();
}

uint64_t stopRec(BOOL log);
uint64_t stopRec(BOOL log) {
    uint64_t endTime = mach_absolute_time();

    uint64_t elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;
    if (log) {
        NSLog(@"Recorded Time Gif Image:%llu", elapsedTime);
    }
    return elapsedTime;
}
```

Comment: Try to add exception break point.

Comment: are you using any NSTimer function in rootviewcontroller? Delete all break points and check once

Comment: i had this issues too, but also on Xcode 7 and Xcode 8. I couldnt fix it.

Comment: @karthikeyan I updated my question.  that code is used for gif images frames

Comment: where are you using this code  viewDidload or viewDidApper?

Comment: in side ViewDidLoad

Comment: change to viewDidAppear and check

Comment: @karthikeyan No difference !!! When i removed the exception break point, then its not stopping,  But i expect even i added the  Exception BreakPoint it should not stop.

Comment: now you able to run right, then it could be break point

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153438/discussion-between-kiran-and-karthikeyan).